# Coordinate-free proof: inner product in algebraic tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, tensor-products

If $V,W$ say complex vector spaces, then it is well known fact there is a natural tensor product on $V \otimes W$ defined on the prime tensors by
$$ \langle v \otimes w, v' \otimes w' \rangle  = \langle v , v' \rangle \langle w ,w' \rangle.$$

The problem is to prove that this is acually an inner product.

Conjugation symmetry can be easily proven. However, I'm also need to prove, that it is positively definite. That is, for all $v_i \otimes w_i$ it holds that
$$  \langle v_i \otimes w_i,v_i \otimes w_i\rangle \ge 0 $$
and
$$
\langle v_i \otimes w_i,v_i \otimes w_i\rangle = 0 \iff v_i \otimes w_i
$$
(here I use Einstein summation notation.)
If one considers orthonormal bases $(e_i)_{i \in I}$ and $(f_j)_{j \in J}$ of $\mathrm{span}(v_i) \subset V$ and $\mathrm{span}(w_i) \subset W$ respectevely, then there are scalars $(\alpha)_{i\in I,j \in J}$ such that $v_i \otimes w_i = \alpha_{j,k}(e_j \otimes f_k)$. Then, it is clearly can be seen, that
$$\langle v_i \otimes w_i,v_i \otimes w_i\rangle = |\alpha_{j,k}|^2 \ge 0. $$

> However, I am interested if this fact can be proved without invoking any bases.

What I got by now is the identity

$$
\langle v_i \otimes w_i, v_i \otimes w_i \rangle = 
\sum^n_{i=1} \langle v_i, v_i \rangle \langle w_i, w_i \rangle 
+ \sum^n_{j \neq i} \frac{1}{2}\left(  \langle v_i, v_j \rangle \langle w_i, w_j \rangle + \overline{\langle v_i, v_j \rangle \langle w_i, w_j \rangle} \right)
$$
which is clearly a real value, but I don't know how to prove that it is non-negative.

Comment: @DylanPentland This works only with prime  tensors $v \otimes w$, while general elements $t \in V \otimes W$ have form $t = \sum^n_{i=1} v_i \otimes w_i$ and $\langle  t, t\rangle = \sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1} \langle v_i,v_j \rangle\langle w_i, w_j \rangle$

Comment: Woops, my bad. This question seems to resolve the issue though: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422489/prove-that-sum-i-j-langle-v-i-v-j-rangle-langle-w-i-w-j-rangle-geq-0?rq=1. Your method of picking an orthonormal basis is probably the best way to go.

Comment: @DylanPentland Ok, thanks.

Comment: I suspect that there is a nice coordinate-free proof if we invoke the [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property) that defines the tensor product.

Comment: We want $$\left\langle\sum_i v_i\otimes w_i,\sum_j v_j\otimes w_j\right\rangle=\sum_{i,j}\left\langle v_i,v_j\right\rangle\left\langle w_i,w_j\right\rangle\geq0.$$

We know that for any coefficients $a_i$ we have $\left\langle\sum_i a_iv_i,\sum_j a_jv_j\right\rangle\geq 0$ and similarly $\left\langle\sum_k b_kw_k,\sum_l b_lw_l\right\rangle\geq 0$.

Comment: So we can sum several terms of this form to get $$0\leq\sum_I\left\langle\sum_ia_{iI}v_i,\sum_ja_{jI}v_j\right\rangle\left\langle\sum_kb_{kI}w_k,\sum_lb_{lI}w_l\right\rangle=\sum_{I,i,j,k,l}a_{iI}\overline{a_{jI}}b_{kI}\overline{b_{lI}}\left\langle v_i,v_j\right\rangle\left\langle w_k,w_l\right\rangle.$$

So we would be done if we could find $a_{iI}$ and $b_{iI}$ so that $\sum_I a_{iI}\overline{a_{jI}}b_{kI}\overline{b_{lI}}=\begin{cases}1&i=k,j=l\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: @OscarCunningham I am amused to see that solution of this, seemingly mundane, problem is actually can be derives as a consequence of some modification of Hillbert Nullstellansatzs. It seems that it must always be possible to find large enaugh $N$ such that number of equations $2n^4$ is less then number of variables $2n^2N$. The only thing which concerns me, is a complex conjugation and the fact that I will need to work with a real roots. Nevertheless, polynomial equations $P_{i,j,k,l}(a,b) = \sum^N_{I=1}a_{i,I}\overline{a_{j,I}}b_{k,I}\overline{b_{l,I}}$ look highly symmetric and consistent.